# Error in reading csv R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file that should be normally formatted, however, I get the following error message when trying to read it into my working environment:

```
 tram <- read.csv("nariad_tram.csv")
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

How does one go about resolving this?

One method that worked to read in the rile was using tab delineators, but it seems as if the headers are separated by periods as opposed to commas

```
> tram <- read.csv("nariad_tram.csv", sep = "\t")

    > head(tram)
      nrd_identificator.cnrd_orderby.nd_identificator.park_identificator.cp_regnum.cp_shortname.cp_latitude.cp_longitude.cnrd_daynight.cnrd_endstation.cnrd_speckp.cnrd_timeplan.cnrd_timefact.cnrd_diflextion.cnrd_marsh.mr_title
    1                                                                                    59418483,140,5941,203,5365,Детск,55.82937933,37.76646164,D,E,F,298,322,24,13,Детский санаторий (к/ст, пос.) Каланчевская ул. (выс., пос.)
    2                                                                                      59418483,130,5941,203,7118,М.БУЛ,55.81301921,37.73560374,D,,-,289,307,0,13,Детский санаторий (к/ст, пос.) Каланчевская ул. (выс., пос.)
    3                                                                                      59418483,120,5941,203,6241,М.Пре,55.79639691,37.71787001,D,,-,280,290,0,13,Детский санаторий (к/ст, пос.) Каланчевская ул. (выс., пос.)
    4                                                                                     59418483,110,5941,203,14018,М.Сок,55.78826494,37.67965027,D,,-,272,278,0,13,Детский санаторий (к/ст, пос.) Каланчевская ул. (выс., пос.)
    5                                                                                      59418483,100,5941,203,4190,мКрас,55.77910559,37.66552693,D,,-,266,272,0,13,Детский санаторий (к/ст, пос.) Каланчевская ул. (выс., пос.)
    6                                                                                  59418483,90,5941,203,13920,Комсо,55.7752844438,37.6558319272,D,,-,263,271,0,13,Детский санаторий (к/ст, пос.) Каланчевская ул. (выс., пос.)
```

Comment: please shows us what are you writing .

Comment: And show us an example of a csv file that fails. Please post only a short example.

Comment: Adding the `read.csv` line is not enough to replicate the error. [It's always best to create a minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, it would be useful to provide a smaller version of your csv file. One possible cause that I can think of is that some columns contain values that contain commas. Since commas are used to distinguish columns, you end up with more columns than you want, thus rendering your error.

Comment: Define your separator argument in the read.csv line  maybe what you need to do .

Comment: how can I create a reproducible example when I cannot even open the file or read it into R?

Comment: I've read the file into R (see edit above), but it seems that the header and body are separated differently

Comment: If headers are creating problems, you can add `skip=1` argument in `read.csv` and then add headers manually after you get your file into the system if there aren't many variables or you should clean your data first if you can .

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
data<- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
```

Comment: Does headers are seperated by comma

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned the column headers and the data are separated differently..

```
tram <- read.csv("nariad_tram.csv", sep = "\t",skip=1)
colnames(tram) =c("nrd_identificator",
"cnrd_orderby",
"nd_identificator",
"park_identificator",
"cp_regnum",
"cp_shortname",
"cp_latitude",
"cp_longitude",
"cnrd_daynight",
"cnrd_endstation",
"cnrd_speckp",
"cnrd_timeplan",
"cnrd_timefact",
"cnrd_diflextion",
"cnrd_marsh",
"mr_title")
```